# Overriding Python f-strings in VS Code textMateRules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, textmate

In VS Code, I am looking for a way to enforce the usage of a specific Textmate rule, overriding what VS Code uses instead of the one that I would like it to use.

My VS Code version is:

```
Version: 1.63.0
Commit: 7db1a2b88f7557e0a43fec75b6ba7e50b3e9f77e
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
```

In my `settings.json`, I have custom color overrides for various Textmate scopes.

In particular, I have this snippet and its purpose is to enforce the usage of color `black` for attribute names ("variables") unless it is an f-string, in which case I would like to for the entire f-string to be `green`. Note that I would like for the whole of the f-string to be green (not the "f" letter, however) - no matter if it contains attribute access or not.

```json
{
    "scope": [
        "meta.member.access.python",
    ],
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#000",
        "fontStyle": ""
    }
},

{
    "scope": [
        "meta.fstring.python",
    ],
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#007f00",
        "fontStyle": "italic"
    }
},
```

Instead, what I am getting is on the screenshot below, where you can see that `self.hello` is still black and, upon checking what Textmate rules match these elements, I see that it is `meta.member.access.python` indeed.

[VS Code Textmate rules f-strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8G00.png)

The question is how I can achieve what I am looking for?

Either a way to ignore other rules when I am in an f-string or a way to somehow combine the rules, e.g. use specific settings for `meta.member.access.python` only when it is within an f-string?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  {
    "scope": [
      "meta.fstring.python constant.character.format.placeholder.other.python",
      "meta.fstring.python variable.language.special.self.python",
      "source.python meta.fstring.python string.interpolated.python string.quoted.single.python",
      "meta.fstring.python"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "foreground": "#00ff0d",
      "fontStyle": "italic"
    }
  },
```

I can not reproduce your status, I don't know which Color Theme you are using, and the different color themes will modify the scope and color it. But you can override it like the above example.

Comment: Thanks Steven, that pointed me in the right direction. I also had to delete `meta.member.access.python` from the scope using the black color and it is fine now. I did not realize that it was possible to concatenate the scopes in the way you did it, that was most useful!